# How to add plugin by setup callback?

Tags: javascript, callback, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE 4.9.2. It has a [setup callback](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#setup) that is called before the TinyMCE editor is rendered. Assume I have something like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea', 
  setup: function (editor) {
        tinymce_setup_callback(editor);        
  }
});
```

How would I add a plugin in

```
tinymce_setup_callback(editor){}
```

? Is it possible to add a new plugin without overwriting the plugins from the constructor?

I know that one can provide an array of plugins in the `tinymce.init` constructor, but in my scenario I only have access to `tinymce_setup_callback`.

Also, is it possible to overwrite the function `init_instance_callback` in the setup callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once TinyMCE runs its init you cannot add/remove plugins - the editor has no APIs to do such a thing.

If you need to restart the editor with different plugins you could `remove()` and `init()` the editor with the changed configuration.

Comment: Yes thats true, with `init_instance_callback` you can't add/remove plugins. However, I thought the setup callback is called before it is initialized. I have read somewhere that its possible to add plugins with `setup` but it was not explained how.